# How to use value from a label and do calculation

Tags: javascript

I have an issue i havent been able to solve. could anyone help please. I have a selectbox VAT where a user select oui or non. if yes i must apply a 15% tax on the the soustotal value.

im getting the values from a table:

```
    <tr>
        <td class="centrer bold">Sous-total</td><td></td>
        <td><label id="soustotal" class="soustotal"><?php echo (number_format($sousTotal,2)); ?></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="centrer bold">VAT</td>
        <td>
            <select id="cmbvat" name="cmbvat" class="vat" style="width:100px" onchange="updateInput()">
                <option value="0">Non</option>
                <option value="15">Oui</option>
            </select> 
        </td>
        <td><label class="vat"><?php echo (number_format($VAT,2)); ?></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="centrer bold">Total TTC</td><td></td>
        <td><label class="grandtotal"><?php echo (number_format(($sousTotal - $VAT),2)); ?></label></td>
    </tr>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
function updateInput()
{
    var vat = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("cmbvat")[0].value);
    var soustotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("soustotal").innerHTML);

    var vatvalue = (vat * soustotal);

    alert(vatvalue);

}
```

alert(vatvalue) return 15 ??
alert(soustotal) return 1 when it should be 1,910.00;

I get 1,910.00 without parseFlaot:  soustotal = document.getElementById("soustotal").innerHTML;

Its only when i pass parseFloat to soustotal that im getting the value 1 instead of 1,910.00 ...

Comment: You don't need to call `parseFloat(soustotal)`, it's already a float.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by *not working*

Comment: its working for me

Comment: I think it was the typo which is edited now. You used `Var` instead of `var`

Comment: i check ur snippet but its not working for me....this is what im doing: i have a selectbox  where im getting the vat 15%. I need to calculate the vat amout: im failing

Comment: i get value = 1 the moment i do parseFloat(soustotal), why??

Comment: Because valid floating point numbers in JavaScript don’t contain a thousands separator, that’s why.

Comment: @04FS..i feel like you got the right answer...how would u go about it

Answer (score 1):

```js
function updateInput() {
  if (document.getElementById("qui").selected) {
    var soustotal = Number(document.getElementById("soustotal").innerHTML);
    var tax = (10 * parseFloat(soustotal) / 100);
    document.getElementById("vat").innerHTML = tax;
    document.getElementById("grandtotal").innerHTML = tax + soustotal;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("vat").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("grandtotal").innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>VAT</title>
  <script src="Sjabloon.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table style="width:50%">
    <tr>
      <td class="centrer bold">Sous-total</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><label id="soustotal" class="soustotal">5</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="centrer bold">VAT</td>
      <td>
        <select id="cmbvat" name="cmbvat" class="vat" style="width:100px" onchange="updateInput()">
          <option value="0" id="non">Non</option>
          <option value="15" id="qui">Oui</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><label class="vat" id="vat"></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="centrer bold">Total TTC</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><label class="grandtotal" id="grandtotal"></label></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

This works fine for me. At least if this is what you wanted?

Hope this helps.

Comment: soustotal return NaN with number()

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/uv786wy2/

```
var soustotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("soustotal").innerHTML);
var tax = ((10 * (soustotal))/100);
document.getElementById('tax').textContent = tax;
```

Comment: I have updated my code above to give a better picture of what im doing

Comment: @Dave it sounds like you're having a math problem more than a javascript problem. Is that accurate?

Comment: @TKol...not really a math problem...if i can return the value of var and soustotal..im good....but i keep getting value 1 whenever i pass  parseFloat to soustotal...

Comment: @Dave have you tried using the Chrome debugger to set breakpoints to make sure the values are what you expect? `parseFloat('1.1')` returns 1.1 pretty reliably to me, so I don't know why it's not giving you what you expect.

Comment: Here Friends...I thank you all for your efforts. This how i i managed to fixed the problem:

 var vatamount = soustotal.replace(',', '');

 vatamount = vatamount.replace(/[^0-9,.]*/, '');

 vatamount = parseFloat(vatamount);

Comment: @Dave nobody here could have guessed that the problem was that your input contained commas. You didn't give anybody anything to work with!